# Can you start another activity twice within one program?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use the android studio training to create my own project. This issue is that the Extra_MESSAGE symbol cant be resolved. I need help fixing the errors.

**The error**
Error:(21, 60) error: cannot find symbol variable EXTRA_MESSAGE
Error:(20, 70) error: cannot find symbol variable EXTRA_MESSAGE
C:\Users\Michael Jr\Desktop\Final\app\src\main\java\mike\afinal\DisplayMessageActivity.java
C:\Users\Michael Jr\Desktop\Final\app\src\main\java\mike\afinal\DisplayMessageActivity2.java
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

My AndroidManifest

```
     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick (View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void sendMessage (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    }


My DisplayMessageActvity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }

        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
        public void sendMessage(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity2.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

    }
```

My DisplayMessageActvity2

```
   package mike.afinal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class DisplayMessageActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message2);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor ="#FF0"
        android:text=" I added a black backround to better the contrast."
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

    <Button
        android:text="Toast Example"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity_display_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context="mike.afinal.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:textColor ="#FF0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />
```

My activity_display_message2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_message2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mike.afinal.DisplayMessageActivity2">

</RelativeLayout>
```

My strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Final Project</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Start new activity</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I didn't see a definition for `EXTRA_MESSAGE` in `MainActivity`. Moreover, I think you accidentally did a `static import AlarmManager.EXTRA_MESSAGE`.